# Event kit Store event in calendar will change the Time zone issue

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekevent

```
+(NSString *)setCalendarEvent:(NSString *)title withStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate withEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate withAlarmBefore:(NSTimeInterval )alarmTime{




     EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

        EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        event.title     = title;
        event.startDate = startDate;
        event.endDate   = endDate;

        NSMutableArray *myAlarmsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        EKAlarm *alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-alarmTime];
        [myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm1];
        event.alarms = myAlarmsArray;

        [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err;

        [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
        NSString* eventId = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventIdentifier];
        return eventId;

}
```

whenever I store the date in the calender it doesn't store the actual date .

I want to store the exact date which is coming from **CMS** how we can prevent the **iOS** calender by changing its time zone .